# JavaScript - Automate login

Tags: javascript, html

I have an API that connects to Camera with live view. My problem is that there is authentication so every time i try to access i get pop up message that i need to input username and password. I am trying to stream this camera view into one of the div of HTML page:

```
   <div class="card-body">
       <div class="chart-area">
       <img id = "cam_view" src= "http://192.168.1.21/api/scene/rectl">
       <script src="static/style_image.css"></script>
       </div>
   </div>
```

So if i add username and password to pop up window below. i get the camera live video:

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to embed this user name and password so when html page opens it automatically send user name and password and start live streaming without getting this pop up message and me doing it manually.
I am assuming I need to use javascript with on load function.

What i tried so far is adding username and and password in front of API:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="chart-area">
    <img id = "cam_view" src= 
    "http://admin:something@192.168.1.21/api/scene/rectl">
    <script src="static/style_image.css"></script>
    </div>
</div>
```

But with this i get error that the this method is being depreciated and it doesn't work anymore.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use url in format `http://username:passwor@192.168.1.21/api/scene/rectl`

Comment: As far as I am concerned JavaScript won't do the trick.

Comment: @leun4m JS is fully capable to handle basic authentication

Comment: @Justinas Sorry, I foolishly thought of JavaScript filling in the textboxes (Selenium-like)...

Answer (score -3):

That's HTTP basic authentication. Embed your image the following way and it will work:

```
<img id = "cam_view" src= "http://username:password@192.168.1.21/api/scene/rectl">
```

You don't need any Javascript for this

Comment: I have tried <img id = "cam_view" src= "http://username:password@192.168.1.21/api/scene/rectl"> and this didnt work. I am getting error message that site cant be reached. But if i use http://192.168.130.31/api/scene/rectl i do get message i mentioned above and once i enter the credentials i am able to see the live view.

Comment: Have you changed the credentials given in the URL to those you are using?

Comment: I just double checked and here is what i get when i use your solution in my div code:
[Deprecation] Subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials (e.g. `https://user:pass@host/`) are blocked. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856 for more details.

Comment: This is the reason i was looking for javascript solution since this is not allowed anymore.

Comment: So, then move forward: what have you tried to resolve the problem?